# Always show absolutely position divs on top of parents siblings

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a dynamic number of rows inside.
Each row has an absolutely positioned tooltip that triggers on hover. 
The absolutely positioned tooltips are covered by the parent's following siblings.

Here is a simple reproduction of the issue:

```css
.row-containers {
  height: 250px;
  width: 600px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) {background: #DDD}

.row:nth-child(even) {background: white}

.tooltip {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: seagreen;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-containers">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tooltip">
    Hello I am hidden from view by my parent's siblings.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tooltip">
    Hello I am hidden from view by my parent's siblings.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tooltip">
    Hello I am hidden from view by my parent's siblings.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Why this happens is known: later siblings take higher precedence over the children of earlier siblings, regardless of z-index/absolute positioning.

In a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175833/how-can-i-show-child-element-above-parent-element-and-siblings-of-the-parent-ele#_=_) where only one absolutely positioned div needed to take priority, the easy solution was to give the parent a z-index value.

But in my case, every single row and its siblings have an absolutely positioned div that needs to show. Giving every row a z-index value is not a very elegant solution, as they would each need a different z index. It would entail something along the lines of dynamically adding descending Z-values using javascript.

Is there a way to have all the absolute position divs show up on top of their parent's siblings using only html/css?

Comment: remove z-index from .row and add any value of z-index to tooltip

Comment: I guess one possible approximation would be to set every other row except the one being hovered to a lower z-index: `.row:hover ~ .row { z-index: 4; }`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jzmf8L2r/ ...